# Exposing jquery plugin with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) with Webpack. In my view file I have the following:

```
define(function (require) {
    require('bootstrap-daterangepicker');

    $('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker({ ... });
});
```

And in `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
]
```

This results in `daterangepicker is not a function`. I've taken a look at [`daterangepicker.js`](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/blob/master/daterangepicker.js#L1294), and it seems that `$.fn.daterangepicker` is not exported correctly. How would I do this? I've tried using `imports-loader` to force import jQuery, but that didn't help.

Comment: Note that daterangepicker has a line like `jQuery = require('jquery');`. I have a feeling it might bind the plugin to wrong instance of jQuery due to this. In case you don't bundle jQuery, you should set up [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals).

Comment: How would I use `externals`? I was thinking something like `externals: { 'bootstrap-daterangepicker': '$' }`, but that doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: If you have just `externals: {jquery: true}` it will treat jQuery as an external and won't include it the bundle. In that case your datepicker will hook it up through global by the looks of it.

Comment: Hm that does not work. It looks like bootstrap-daterangepicker does use the correct jQuery, because it is not included in the package. I think the error is purely in the exporting `$` part. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) with some extra strategies. Maybe one of those will do the trick.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently `bootstrap-daterangepicker` tries to load his own jQuery. Therefore `$.fn.daterangepicker` is not available in 'my' jQuery. I've forced `bootstrap-daterangepicker` to include my jQuery with this line in webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery': require.resolve('jquery'),
    }
}
```

Comment: This resolved my issue with `devbridge-autocomplete` too, thanks

Comment: OMG. Thanks so much. You are saved my night.

Comment: Worked for me!! Should be added to the officiel daterangepicker doc

Answer (score 1):

The webpack 'resolve' option didn't help me but @spacek33z comments lead me to realize that my Angular component's linked element wasn't a jQuery element but an ordinary DOM element.  The reason why was that Angular was using its own jqLite vs. the real jQuery.

Searching for why Angular wasn't finding the real jQuery I found the question '[Webpack: how to make angular auto-detect jQuery and use it as angular.element instead of jqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065931/webpack-how-to-make-angular-auto-detect-jquery-and-use-it-as-angular-element-in)' that helped me realize Angular needs `window.jQuery`.

So this seems to be the proper `webpack.conf.js` incantation for me:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         'jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
         'jquery': 'jquery',
  'window.jquery': 'jquery',
         '$'     : 'jquery',
  'window.$'     : 'jquery'
}),
```