# Webpack: how to make angular auto-detect jQuery and use it as angular.element instead of jqLite?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack to build an Angular 1.4 project. The project makes use of several jQuery plugins, which are wrapped into angular directives. Those directives internally use `angular.element`, probably implying that angular.element is the real jQuery, not jqLite.

I want angular to auto-detect jQuery and use it instead of jqLite. I tried to require jquery locally in my entry point module `app.js`: `require('jquery')` and to expose jQuery globally with `require(expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery)`.

Still, whatever I do, `angular.element` refers to jqLite.

---

My research resulted in several findings:

1. Even when imported as a CommonJS module, Angular assigns itself to a global variable `window.angular`, so I don't need to `expose` it with Webpack: [Does Angular assign itself to `window.angular` globally, when loaded as CommonJS module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101119/does-angular-assign-itself-to-window-angular-globally-when-loaded-as-commonjs/36106899#36106899).
2. ProviderPlugin doesn't seem to do the trick: it doesn't expose jQuery to global namespace; instead, for every module that depends on global name jQuery, it inserts `require('jquery')` in it. I'm not 100% sure, but looks like Angular doesn't access `jQuery` from global namespace directly, instead, it tries to access `window.jQuery` in `bindJQuery` function, so this approach doesn't help: [Expose jQuery to real Window object with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080148/expose-jquery-to-real-window-object-with-webpack).
3. For the same reason as ProviderPlugin, `imports-loader` seems unfit: Angular wants `window.jQuery`, not just `jQuery`.
4. **With `expose-loader`, jquery makes it to the window object.** My problem was that Babel hoists all of its imports to the top of module in the resulting code. Hence, although `require(expose?jquery!jquery)` was before `import angular from "angular"` in source files, in bundle  `require("angular")` is at the top of the file, before jquery, so by the time Angular is imported, jquery is not yet available. I wonder, how to use Webpack loaders with ECMA6 import syntax.
5. There was a suggestion to use `import` syntax instead of `require` syntax with jquery: `import "jquery"` or `import $ from "jquery"`, not `require(jquery)`: (Petr Averyanov: [How to use Webpack loaders syntax ( imports/exports/expose) with ECMAScript 6 imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150641/how-to-use-webpack-loaders-syntax-imports-exports-expose-with-ecmascript-6-im)). jquery source code is [wrapped with a special wrapper](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/wrapper.js#L41), which idenitifies how jquery is required (with AMD/require, CommonJS or globally with `<script>` statement). Based on that it sets a special argument `noGlobal` for jquery fabric and either creates `window.jQuery` or not, based on the value of `noGlobal`. As of jquery 2.2.4, upon `import "jquery"` `noGlobal === true` and `window.jQuery` is not created. IIRC, some older versions of jquery didn't recognize `import` as CommonJS import and added `import`ed jquery to global namespace, which allowed angular to use it.

---

Details: here's my `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

require("expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery");
require("metisMenu/dist/metisMenu");
require("expose?_!lodash");
require("expose?angular!angular");

import angular from "angular";
import "angular-animate";
import "angular-messages";
import "angular-resource";
import "angular-sanitize";
import "angular-ui-router";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
import "angular-bootstrap";

require("../assets/styles/style.scss");
require("../assets/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css");

// Import all html files to put them in $templateCache
// If you need to use lazy loading, you will probably need
// to remove these two lines and explicitly require htmls
const templates = require.context(__dirname, true, /\.html$/);
templates.keys().forEach(templates);

import HomeModule from "home/home.module";
import UniverseDirectives from "../components/directives";

angular.module("Universe", [
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngMessages",
    "ngResource",
    "ngSanitize",
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap",

    HomeModule.name,
    UniverseDirectives.name,
])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider){
    // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
      .state('test', {
        url: "/test",
        template: "This is a test"
      });
});
```

Comment: How do you load angular and jQuery into your application? Are they in bundle or are loading from CDN?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan They are both in webpack bundle.

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: @maioman Angular 1.4.

Comment: if you load jquery before angular. angular is clever enough to use jquery over jqlite

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Got this answer from [john-reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761388/john-reilly):
[The mysterious case of webpack angular and jquery](http://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2016/05/the-mysterious-case-of-webpack-angular-and-jquery.html)

[bob-sponge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554165/bob-sponge)'s answer is not quite right - the Provide plugin is actually doing a text replacement on modules it processes, so we need to provide `window.jQuery` (which is what angular is looking for) and not just `jQuery`.

> In your `webpack.config.js` you need to add
>   the following entry to your plugins:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
}),
```

> This uses the webpack [ProvidePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#provideplugin) and, at the point of
>   webpackification (© 2016 John Reilly) all references in the code to
>   window.jQuery will be replaced with a reference to the webpack module
>   that contains jQuery. So when you look at the bundled file you'll see
>   that the code that checks the `window` object for `jQuery` has become
>   this:

```
jQuery = isUndefined(jqName) ?
  __webpack_provided_window_dot_jQuery : // use jQuery (if present)
    !jqName ? undefined : // use jqLite
    window[jqName]; // use jQuery specified by `ngJq`
```

> That's right; webpack is providing Angular with jQuery whilst still
>   **not** placing a `jQuery` variable onto the `window`. Neat huh?

Comment: I LOVE YOU, i spent 2 days trying to find out the crazy errors because of this.

Answer (score 9):

## !!Update

Apparently you still need to use the commonJs require for angular in the ES6 example.

```
import $ from "jquery"

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;

var angular = require("angular");
```

below is the original answer

---

---

I want to purpose a easier solution. Just make jQuery a window global so that angular can recognize it:

```
var $ = require("jquery")

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;

var angular = require("angular");
```

or in your case (**OUT DATED**):

```
import $ from "jquery"

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;

import angular from "angular";
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Your solution is good. Besides, I found out that you can just `import jquery; import angular` and angular should detect jquery (see update to the question, #5). Could you test, if that works?

Comment: Hm, I tested it myself. WIth jquery 2.2.4 noGlobal=true with `import $ from "jquery"` and `import "jquery"`.

Comment: And what is your result?

Comment: Ah, sorry, the result is negative - it doesn't work. `jquery`'s wrapper recognizes that it is imported with as a flavor of CommonJS, sets noGlobal to true and doesn't set window.$, thus angular doesn't detect it.

Comment: Can you use my solution with noGlobal=false.

Comment: If jquery were to set its noGlolal=false, it would've assigned window.$ = window.jQuery =$, essentially replicating your solution. I think, more webpack-ish solution is to use expose loader, as suggested in approach #4, as webpack does the same as you do by itself.

Answer (score 3):

In your case is better to use [ProvidePlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin). Just add this lines to your webpack config in plugins section and jquery will available in your app:

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         "$": "jquery",
         "jQuery": "jquery"
    })
```

Comment: Hi, Bob Sponge! This didn't help: 
`angular.element` -> `function JQLite()`. Though, I don't understand, why angular was exported to the global namespace at all - I've commented out the line `require("expose?angular!angular");`.

Comment: In fact, I imported `angular` twice in the `app.js` - locally and globally - which might introduce confusion. I'd like to remove the local import but I can't. WIthout the local `import angular from "angular";` browser curses about `webpack:///./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js?:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined`. The global `require("expose?angular!angular");` was done for debugging purposes and will be removed in production.

Comment: Be sure that you use jQuery  2.1+ and `window.jQuery` is not `undefined`

Comment: jQuery 2.2.1, yes it is availabe under names jQuery and $ (even without ProviderPlugin).

Comment: Actually I'm not using angular with webpack and can only suggest. So, try import jquery directly in angular: `var angular  = require("imports?jQuery=jquery!angular")`

Comment: I did some additional research and updated the question with its results.

Comment: Finally solved it. It was due to Babel, putting import ahead of requires. It rearranged my code, so that angular was always imported before jquery was required. Damn. :)

Comment: Interesting observation, I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing results of your research.

Comment: @Bob: How did you resolve this issue when Babel was rearranging your code. I am facing the same issue and I guess your solution can work for me as well.

Comment: @invincibleDudess I didn't quite solve it - I just replaced all the ECMA6 `import`s with CommonJS `require`s, as there's no way in Webpack to say `require("expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery");` in ECMA6 `import` syntax. Although, there's another solution. It turned out that `jquery`, `lodash` and `angular`, when `import`ed in ECMA6 just add themselves to the `window` object and become globally available, so for them you don't need `expose` loader. So you can just use ECMA6 `import`s everywhere, unless some of your minor libraries requires exposing. Just in case I sticked with `require` so far.

Answer (score 2):

So, I give my solution, which is actually a mashup of the @BobSponge answer and @Bob's hints / comments. So nothing original, just showing what works for me (in a project not using Babel / ES6, BTW) and attempting to explain why it works...

The (final) trick is indeed to use the [expose loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader).

As explained in their page, we have to put in `module.loaders`:

```
{ test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" },
```

Moreover, in the `plugins` list, I have:

```
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
        {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            _: 'lodash',
            // [...] some other libraries that put themselves in the global scope.
            //angular: 'angular', // No, I prefer to require it everywhere explicitly.
        }),
```

which actually finds the global occurrences of these variables in the code, and require them into variables local to each module. It eases the migration of an existing project (from RequireJS to Webpack) as I do...
I think we can do without this plugin if you prefer to be explicit in your imports.

And, importantly (I think), in the entry point of the application, I require them in the order I want them. In my case, I made a vendor bundle, so that's the order in this bundle.

```
require('jquery');

require('lodash');
// [...]

var angular = require('angular');
// Use the angular variable to declare the app module, etc.
```

Webpack will add the libraries to the relevant bundle in the order it sees the `require`s (unless you use a plugin / loader that reorder them).
But the imports are isolated (no global leak), so Angular wasn't able to see the jQuery library. Hence the need for `expose`. (I tried `window.jQuery = require('jquery');` instead, but it didn't work, perhaps it is too late.)

Comment: what do you mean by `in the vendor bundle, as I made one` ? I mean... where exactly do you put that code that defines the order?

Comment: I had to re-read myself a couple time to understand what I meant... :-)
I want these libraries to be ordered in the vendor bundle. The `require`s in the right order are put in the app bundle, ie. in the app code, of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is this japanese article [I want to use the jQuery not jQLite in webpack + AngularJS](http://qiita.com/cither/items/6fed7548e78c2b3ed4d1#%E3%83%99%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AA%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95imports-loader%E3%82%92%E4%BD%B5%E7%94%A8) that seems to talk about the same problem (I don't know Japanese yet btw). I used google to translate to english, credits goes to [cither](http://qiita.com/cither) for this nice answer.

He provides four ways to solve this:

1. Assign directly to the window (not really cool)

   ```
   window.jQuery = require('jquery');
   var angular = require('angular');
   console.log(angular.element('body'));
   //[body, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "body"]
   ```
2. Use the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader#expose-loader-for-webpack) (ok, but not that cool)

   ```
   npm install --saveDev expose-loader
   ```

   `webpack.config.js`

   ```
   module.exports = {
       entry: "./index",
       output: {
           path: __dirname,
           filename: "bundle.js"
       },
       module: {
           loaders: [{
               test: /\/jquery.js$/,
               loader: "expose?jQuery"
           }]
       }
   };
   ```

   usage:

   ```
   require('jquery');
   var angular = require('angular');
   console.log(angular.element('body'));
   //[body, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "body"]
   ```
3. Use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader#expose-loader-for-webpack) (better)

   ```
   npm install --saveDev expose-loader
   ```

   `webpack.config.js`

   ```
       module.exports = {
       entry: "./index",
       output: {
           path: __dirname,
           filename: "bundle.js"
       },
       module: {
           loaders: [{
               test: /\/angular\.js$/,
               loader: "imports?jQuery=jquery"
           }, {
               test: /\/jquery.js$/,
               loader: "expose?jQuery"
           }]
       }
   };
   ```

   usage:

   ```
   var angular = require('angular');
   console.log(angular.element('body'));
   //[body, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "body"]
   ```
4. Use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin) (Best solution)

   *This is actually the same as [studds's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38785528/1092815) here*

   ```
   module.exports = {
       entry: "./index",
       output: {
           path: __dirname,
           filename: "bundle.js"
       },
       plugins: [
           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
               "window.jQuery": "jquery"
           })
       ],
   };
   ```

   usage:

   ```
   var angular = require('angular');
   console.log(angular.element('body'));
   //[body, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "body"]
   ```

I thought I'd share this here since we had the exact same problem. We used the `expose-loader` solution in our project with success. I suppose that the `ProvidePlugin` which injects jquery directly in `window` is also a good idea.