# jQuery Plugin method is not a function - Webpack, VS2017, ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: jquery-plugins, asp.net-core-2.0, webpack-3

**The code below works fine in VsCode + webpack**

**Index.ts:**

```
require("./jQueryPlugin-No-Module");
debugger;
$.fn.test();  // fails here
```

I am using the ProvidePlugin to inject jQuery into this script file.

**jQueryPlugin-No-Module.js:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.test = function () {
        console.log("jQuery-Plugin called with options");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**I have copied the all code from VsCode to VS2017-ASP.NET Core Project and just adapted the paths. Everything runs perfect except the plugin above,
I get this error:**

[image]

In `index.ts` I put a `debugger`  statement. When I run the application it stops there, the plugin `$.fn.test` has been successfully attached to jQuery. I switch to the Chrome console and execute `$.fn.test();` there, works as expected.
I go back to source view and hit F11 to execute the next step and I get the error above.

Perhaps someone has experienced this issue using ASP.NET Core 2 and VS2017 before...?

`tsc && webpack -d --env.dev --display-modules --progress --display-error-details --config webpack.config.dev.js`

Answer (score 4):

[Credits go to > spacek33z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647927/2581562)

The problem was the following:

In my webpack.config.js I had the following jQuery alias pointing to the jquery dist folder:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': require.resolve('jquery'), // --> node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js
```

and my plugins section I configured the `ProvidePlugin` to use the src version of `jQuery` (commented out code):

```
plugins: [

           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",   // <-- right!
            jQuery: "jquery",  // <-- right!
            //$: "jquery/src/jquery",  // <-- wrong!
            //jQuery: "jquery/src/jquery"  // <-- wrong!          
        }),
```

That's why I get another copy of `jQuery` inside of the plugin code in `jQueryPlugin-No-Module.js`.

Adding this jQuery `alias` to my webpack.config.js to point to the jQuery dist folder:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': require.resolve('jquery'), // resolve to dist folder
```

Now I get no error.