# How to right include library in webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Rails 6 with webpack. I want to use library `jquery-textcomplete`, but I don't know how I must include it to `application.js` file.

My steps:

1. I've install `jquery-textcomplete` through `yarn add jquery-textcomplete`
2. I am include this in `application.js` like as `import 'jquery-textcomplete'` or `require('jquery-textcomplete')`
3. I see a library in a compiled js file

But I getting an error `ncaught TypeError: $(...).textcomplete is not a function`. If I include it through `CDN` all work fine. 
Can you please tell me, how I must to do? Help me, please.

**my `webpack/environment.js`**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
)

environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

**my `application.js`**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery");

import 'jquery-textcomplete';
```

**my `package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-textcomplete": "^1.8.5",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878790/exposing-jquery-plugin-with-webpack) helped me. I really didn't notice what I had by default `src` path.