# how to require jquery with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

How to require jquery file with webpack should I have to install from npm, or can I just require the file download from jquery website?

directory

```
app/
./assets/javascripts/article/create/base.js
./assets/javascripts/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
webpack.config.js
```

base.js  error

```
require('../../../lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); 
var Content = function() {
};
module.exports = Content;
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'ArticleCreate':['./assets/javascripts/Article/Create/Base.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: './assets/javascripts/bundle/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
        }
    }
};
```

There is a related answer which shows all options of importing jQuery here: [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

Comment: yes I tried this  `resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: "./assets/javascripts/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
    }
  },`  and use `var $ = require('jquery');`  but if shows error

Comment: I also tried `resolve: {
   root: path.resolve('./assets/javascripts/lib'),
   extensions: ['', '.js']
   },`  and `var $ = require('jquery-1.11.1.min.js');`  it works but I just don't get why can't I use resolve alias ?

Comment: I found why, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/109 seems have to use absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with installing jQuery with npm

`npm install jquery --save`

Then

`var $ = require('jquery'),
    jQuery = $,
    ...`