# Using jQuery with Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, webpack

I'm migrating from RequireJS to Webpack and I'm having some trouble when requiring jQuery for my modules.

I know there are some answers about this and I've gone through them but I can't get it to work. This one: [Managing Jquery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) is the one I've been reading.

My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var bower_dir = __dirname + '/bower_components';

var config = {
    addVendor: function(name, path) {
        this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
        //this.module.noParse.push(new RegExp(path));
    },
    entry: {
        app: ['./app/js/main.js'],
        vendors: ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    },
    resolve: { alias: {} },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jquery": "jquery"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        noParse: [bower_dir + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'],
        loaders: []
    }
};

config.addVendor('jquery', bower_dir + '/jquery/jquery.js');
config.addVendor('bootstrap', bower_dir + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');

module.exports = config;
```

I'm using **ProvidePlugin** to require jQuery on every module that uses it.
Also, I'm putting vendor libraries in a **vendors.js** file and my modules in **main.js**.

My **main.js** file has this few lines of code just to test if $ resolves to jQuery:

```
$(".search-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".search-container").toggle();
});
```

And my **index.html** has these lines in :

```
<script src="<s:url  value="/resources/build/vendors.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<s:url  value="/resources/build/bundle.js"/>"></script>
```

When I run my app I get **Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function** in the console even though **$** is in the global scope.

I'd really appreciate if you could give me a hand with this because I've been writing and rewriting my code and getting nowhere.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you by any chance using the minifed jQuery? This [might be](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/108#issuecomment-26270583) the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `webpack.ProvidePlugin`, you could just use https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader:

`loaders: [{
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery',
}]`