# webpack & jQuery: not playing nicely together

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, webpack

I am trying to use the carousel component of bootstrap in an Angular 2 application that I am developing using webpack. I am having real problems requiring bootsrap.js and jQuery.js.

There are many, many posts on this subject on stackoverflow and elsewhere on the world wide interweb. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack), for example, looked really promising but I followed it to the letter and still get the error in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

In my component's definition file, I have the two rather smelly and suspect looking requires:

```
require("../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js");
require('../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js');
```

I have tried the non-minified version of the bootstrap,.js, along with several variations on the require, such as `require('jquery')` but the error persists.

Please help! I have had this working on another project and can't understand why jQuery isn't playing along.

---

One thing I would like to do is to simply require the jQuery library directly in the component, like this:

```
window.jquery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

The TypeScript compiler complained, predictably. Creating an window interface that includes the `$` and `jquery` members had no effect. The compiler complained nonetheless.

I would be happy with this solution at the moment, until I can find a less smelly solution.

Thoughts or solutions great appreciated and rewarded with virtual doughnuts.

---

Hmm. Following basarat's advice, I tried the following:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
import bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
```

This yielded errors in VSC and webpack: `cannot find module jquery`, and `cannot find module bootstrap-sass`. Oddly, removing the assignments, like this:

```
require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

...and the modules were magically found. With a different error regarding sizzle, but at least it found the modules.

Thoughts?

Comment: `and the modules were magically found. ` Modules found at `compile` time and at `runtime` are different things. To be found at `compile` time you need TypeScript definitions (e.g. `typings install --ambient jquery`). You will need to write `bootstrap-sass` definitions yourself

Comment: That didn't solve the issue and it is occurring at compile time. Even before compile: VS Code highlights it. But it's odd that it should happen only if you prepend `import $ =`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the two rather smelly and suspect looking requires

It should be:

```
import $ = require('jquery');  // 1 
import bootstrap = require('bootstrap');  // 2
```

Anything else is wrong. I can assure you that `1` just works. The issue is with `bootstrap` and its npm package. If you have these imports in this order that should just work as well. Compile with `--module commonjs`.

Comment: Well I'm using bootstrap-sass but I will modify and give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I tried implementing your advice and received further errors. Please see my original post, I have added detail there.