# webpack: Do I need to install webpack to use bundle.js

Tags: webpack

I have installed `webpack` locally and I'm uploading the `bundle.js` on server and I call it using script tag from server's `index.html`. Doing this the `bundle.js` is not able to call jquery module inside the bundle itself. So my doubt is do i need to install webpack on server so that my `bundle.js` works properly.

Help is super ultra highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install Webpack on your server. However libraries like jQuery are handled differently when using them with Webpack.

Since I don't know what your Webpack config looks like, I can only guess that you may need to use a strategy like [the one answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

Comment: Yeah, actually i'm getting error because jQuery is also used. Anyway i got a heads up with your answer. I'll share my webpack.config too