# The Vue was unable to invoke the API of JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, vue.js

I hope used some APIs from JQuery UI, such as draggable(). but it doesn't work. I found the possible cause is that there is null object for $.ui in Vue invoking. Would you like to share some experiences for this please?

Comment: if you are using webpack you might need to use the webpack.ProvidePlugin for jQuery. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: Could you explain your problem in greater depth? Here is a jsfiddle which applies draggable() to a vue js component: https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/dj8uujky/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Jquery UI and Vue js without compatibility issues. If you want to make a component draggable you'll need to attach any handlers **after** vue has updated the DOM.

A component's html element can be accessed via its `$el` property. From the [Vue js Lifecycle Diagram](https://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) we can see that `$el` will be available during the `ready` lifecycle hook.

Knowing this, we can make a component `draggable()` with the following code:

```
Vue.component('draggable-widget', {
    template: '#draggable-widget',

    ready: function() {
        $(this.$el).draggable();
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/dj8uujky/) showing it in action.

Comment: I use  Vue.nextTick(function () {} ... it also work, let me try your way if am idele, thanks! I thought your answer mus be correct!

Comment: If you are making the component draggable from the parent Vue instance, or from a parent component, then the `$nextTick` function is likely necessary. The way I explained works if the component is making *itself* draggable. Glad you got it working!