# Webpack importing video.js returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, webpack, video.js

I am trying to use video.js via webpack.

I installed video.js via npm - `npm install video.js --save-dev`

In webpack I read that video.js should be loaded via script loader else it throws an error.

This is how I am loading video.js through the babel loader

```
module: 
   loaders: [
      {
                test: /video\.js/,
                loader: 'script'
      }
   ]
```

I got this solution from here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2750

This is my import statement

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
```

The issue that I now face is the import is returning an empty object, so when I try to do this:

```
var vidTag = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.html5Video);

this.videojs = videojs(vidTag);
```

I get this error:

**renderer-0.js:8031 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _video2.default) is not a function(…)**

Any help will be much appreciated. I am new to ES6 / React / Webpack

Answer (score 3):

**Please take a look at the loader's README before copy&pasting some random code**. The [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) is not appropiate here, because it imports scripts into the global scope while skipping the whole module system.

So, if you wanted to use the script-loader, you would just write:

```
import "script-loader!video.js";

console.log(videojs); // should be an object now
```

Usually I would not recommend the use of the script-loader because it neglects the whole point of a module system where you import stuff *explicitly into the local scope*. In the example above, the import happens as a *side-effect into the global scope* which is effectively the same as just using a `<script>` tag with all its downsides like name clashes, etc.

There are often better alternatives to it, like the [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader), which appends a `module.exports` at the end of the module, thus turning an old-school global script into a CommonJS module.

In this particular case, however, you don't need a loader at all because video.js is already aware of a CommonJS module system. Just write `import videojs from "video.js";`.

There is another minor problem, however. If you compile this with webpack, it will print a warning to the console:

```
WARNING in ../~/video.js/dist/video.js
Critical dependencies:
13:480-487 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ../~/video.js/dist/video.js 13:480-487
```

This is because webpack detects that this file has already been bundled somehow. Often it's better to include the actual `src` with all its tiny modules instead of one large `dist` because this way webpack is able to optimize the bundle in a better way. I've written down an [exhaustive explanation about how to import legacy scripts with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/1343851).

Unfortunately, video.js does not include its `src` in the version deployed at npm, so you're forced to use the `dist`. In order to get rid of the error message and to improve webpack's build time, you can instruct webpack to skip video.js when parsing the code for `require()` statements by setting the [`module.noParse`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-noparse) option in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
    module: {
        noParse: [
            /node_modules[\\/]video\.js/
        ]
    }
```

Usually it's safe to flag all pre-bundled modules (typically those with a `dist` folder) as `noParse` because they are already self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer the issue that I face when doing import videojs from "video.js", was that it says cannot assign vttjs to undefined. Which is mentioned in the github issue i pasted above. Will the no parse property take care of that ?

Comment: Nope. But I've tested my solution with the latest version of videojs and it worked. So, if the error is still there, you need to provide an example.

Comment: Should be: `noParse: [ /node_modules(\\|\/)video\.js/ ]` , FYI - using `noParse` will not work together with the `expose` plugin.

Comment: I was using script-loader but this seems like a cleaner solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

include SDN

```
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video.min.js"></script>
```

webpack config:

```
config.externals = {
    'video.js': 'videojs'
};
```