# jquery is not loading in my app.js.it is not importing through node_modules.i am using web pack,there i mentioned alias

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack

I am trying to integrate jquery in webpack in angularjs. I tried many ways it not working for me. Actually i am trying to import jquery from node_modules, but it is not importing. please suggest me some way. Because of unloading jQuery, every where giving error,

> jQuery is not defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: @Sherin,i tried all way,it is not working form me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to run jquery code inside Angular. This is not supported and you should find a way to do things the Angular way instead of the jQuery way.
This is somewhat of a mindset change you will find that once you do everything the Angular way you would never have to ever write a jQuery selector $("#foo") again.

Comment: I am trying to integrate angular-slick,it depends on jquery slick js file,this file depends on jquery file.so i need to import jquery.i tried to import as external file and also from node_modules,it is not loading

Comment: could you post your index file, you don't need to import anything you simply need to link to jquery.js before angular.js

Comment: if i use cdn it is working.atleast considering file.if i import ,it is showing error ,'jQuery' is not defined in transition.js(bootstrap).if i solve this,again in slick file,'jQuery' is not defined

Comment: import jQuery from 'jquery';

import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import angular_animate from 'angular-animate'
import angularSanatize from 'angular-sanitize';
import formly from 'angular-formly';
import formlyBootstrap from 'angular-formly-templates-bootstrap';
import uibootstrap from 'angular-bootstrap-npm';
import ngMessages from 'angular-messages';
import ngCookies from 'angular-cookies';
import 'angular-file-upload';
//module declaration

Comment: not sure why you are using import statements, I suggest you start with an angular-seed template, use <script> tags to link to jquery and the slick carousel

Comment: ya i used this,again,slick is not function.for this they are saying jquery file should load first.what i should do for this

Comment: from three days i am trying to solve this.i am not finding why it is like this.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ transition.js:59(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:1643__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ npm.js:2(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:1637__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ app.js:93(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:491__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ multi_app:2(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:47__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:40(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:43

Comment: I have found over long time that if the component doesn't play nice, try a different component. There are lot's of carousels that you can use https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

Comment: If we want to import any library,they should export that module.In jQuery they did not export module,so we can not import.