# Issue with es6 import which was fixed by using require

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, import, ecmascript-6, require

Given the following code I started my `bootstrap.js` file with:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

// jQuery
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

// Twitter bootstrap
import 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap';

// Initialize theme
import './theme/bootstrap';
```

When I compiled this (using webpack) and ran it in my browser I got the following complaint from bootstrap: 'I need jQuery to work...'

I didn't (and still don't) understand why jQuery wasn't imported, I'm setting it to the global window object 1 rule above bootstrap.

However when I change my code and remove all imports:

```
// jQuery
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

// Twitter bootstrap
require('bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap');

// Initialize theme
require('./theme/bootstrap');
```

This code is working perfectly fine and everything is working as expected, but what I always thought was that import and require are basically the same thing and that import was just getting transpiled to a require call. This is apparently not the case, can someone explain to me what exactly is happening here and why require is working while import is not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/1815058

Comment: Imports are processed before the file starts to execute, so your `window.$` assignment will run after all the imports.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Short but clear anwer, if you could add a reply I will accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` statements are processed before a file begins executing, meaning that the ordering of `import` statements relative to code in the file itself will have no effect. `require` calls on the other hand are just function calls, so the ordering has an effect.

In your first example, all of the imports will have executed before the `window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;` line runs.