# webpack jquery plugin perfect-tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack

I'm trying to load the perfect-tooltip jquery plugin (http://tborychowski.github.io/perfecttooltip/) using webpack.
I successfully loaded other jquery plugins like: typed.js and backstretch by following the instructions provided here ([Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)) but they don't seem to work with that specific plugin.

When I run the bundle an error tells me that the tooltip function (exported by the plugin) is not defined. It seems the plugin is not loaded by jquery. I thought the plugin tried to load its own instance of jquery so I used an alias:

```
alias: {
  'jquery': require('jquery'),
}
```

It didn't solve the problem.

My current webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var moment = require('moment');
var path = require('path');
var environment = process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT || 'dev';

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: '[name].browser.' + moment().format('DDMMYYYYHHmm') + '.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts!angular2-template' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, include: path.resolve('src/app'), loader: 'raw-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, exclude: path.resolve('src/app'), loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css', {
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
          loader: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.html', '.css']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      app: {
        environment: JSON.stringify(environment),
        config: JSON.stringify(require('./profile/' + environment + ".profile.js"))
      }
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(
      ['dist']
    ),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/images', to: 'images' }
    ]),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].browser.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to load that script. 
The package.json file provided in the package doesn't have a main property, Webpack was simply trying to bundle all files in the package.
I solved that by requiring two specific files: "js/jquery.tooltip.js" and "css/tooltip.css".