# How to configure and use jQuery with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack

I have a very simple project to test run jQuery function with webpack. However I ran into errors at the bundle step. Here are the errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jsdom' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/jQuery/lib
 @ ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 5:13-29

ERROR in ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'xmlhttprequest' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/jQuery/lib
 @ ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 8:28-53

ERROR in ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'location' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/jQuery/lib
 @ ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 13:24-43

ERROR in ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'navigator' in /home/mypc/IdeaProject/OpenDimSum/frontend/node_modules/jQuery/lib
 @ ./~/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 17:25-45
```

Here are my config files:
package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2",
    "react": "file:node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "file:node_modules/react-dom",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'public',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {

        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        include: APP_DIR,
      }
    ]
  },

};

module.exports = config;
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import $ from 'jQuery'


(function () {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("It works!");
    });

})();
```

If I install the mentioned modules (jsdom, xmlhttprequest, ..), the errors will be replaced by very long errors.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to resolve the jQuery as a global identifier. When you use `ProvidePlugin` you dont want to import `jQuery` into the modules since it would be available as global variable.

something like

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a third "line" to this, that says `jquery: "jquery"`?  I am getting error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'`, and I am wondering if it is because only `$` and `jQuery` are specified, and not `jquery` with the lowercase `q`?