# Typescript 2.0.3 with @types definitions, Webpack, Foundation, jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, typescript, types, webpack, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to build an application with TypeScript 2.0.3 with @types definitions and want to use foundation-sites and bundle everything with webpack.
As soon as I try to import foundation, I get the console error message that jQuery is not defined.
When I don't import foundation, jQuery works fine!

If anyone could explain, what I'm doing wrong and how to load e.g. Foundation Tooltip from a .ts file, that would be really awesome.

You can check out the complete source here: https://github.com/Der-Alex/typescript-foundation-webpack

What I am doing is kind of basic: 
I've got an ./app folder. Inside there is an app.ts, main.scss and index.html.

I installed the following npm packages:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "@types/foundation-sites": "^6.1.28",
  "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
  "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
  "foundation-sites": "^6.2.3",
  "jquery": "^2.1.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "ts-loader": "^0.9.1",
  "typescript": "^2.0.3",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: './app/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

my ./app/app.ts:

```
import './main.scss';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'foundation-sites';

$(() => {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

There are no transpile / compile errors. When I run webpack-dev-server and check the result in the browser, the styles are loaded but I get this error message 'jQuery is not defined'. The browser understands $ but for example not $(...).on(...);
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work with webpack only!
With some important info from a dev colleague I found that post: 
[Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

This gave me the following hint:

1. Require jquery under the global namespace

   `global.jQuery = require('jquery');`
2. Add an alias

   `resolve: {
       extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
       alias: {
           jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
       }
   }`
3. Add $ and jQuery as a plugin

   `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
   })`

This makes jQuery a global object and can be used inside .ts files like so:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
$(document).foundation();
```

I think, this is the cleanest way of loading jQuery with webpack. 
So I would really appreciate if this answer is voted up.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case problem is caused by the fact that if jQuery is imported using webpack (CommonJS style by default) it doesn't create global `jQuery` variable that `foundation-sites` is relying on. You could try to expose it in your code and see if it fixes the problem:

`import * as $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
import 'foundation-sites';`

Comment: Thank you so much, Stubb0rn!

Comment: I had to change window.$ to window['jQuery']. TypeScript doesn't allow to add a property in . syntax. But now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to the compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json file:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
]
```

Comment: Hi @Macondiana. I am not sure, how this should help me with my problem. typeRoots only tells typescript, where to look for which typings. My problem is, that webpack doesn't include a global jQuery.