# webpack jquery plugin loading its own instance of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack, jquery-terminal

I've been trying to load a jquery plugin through webpack.
This plugin is packaged as a npm module and in its dependencies includes only jquery.
I think webpack loads that instance of jquery instead of using the one I provide globally with the ProvidePlugin.
I tried all the solutions provided in another stackoverflow post ([Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)) but they didn't make the trick; the result is always the same: "terminal() is not a function".
If I manually modify the package in the node_modules folder deleting the jquery dependency in the package.json and the downloaded dependency in the node_modules plugin folder webpack successfully binds the plugin with the global instance of jquery.
I know, I could simply make a fork of that package and use a private npm repository but I would like to use the official package.

That's my webpack configuration:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var moment = require('moment');
var path = require('path');
var environment = process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT || 'dev';

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts'
  },
  /*devtool: 'source-map',*/
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: '[name].browser.' + moment().format('DDMMYYYYHHmm') + '.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts!angular2-template' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, include: path.resolve('src/app'), loader: 'raw-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, exclude: path.resolve('src/app'), loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css', {
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
          loader: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]" },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.html', '.css']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      app: {
        environment: JSON.stringify(environment),
        config: JSON.stringify(require('./profile/' + environment + ".profile.js"))
      }
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(
      ['dist']
    ),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/images', to: 'images' }
    ]),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].browser.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

Here the jquery.terminal package.json:

```js
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "jquery.terminal@0.11.11",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "jquery.terminal",
        "name": "jquery.terminal",
        "rawSpec": "0.11.11",
        "spec": "0.11.11",
        "type": "version"
      },
      "/home/giovanni/Projects/Private/site"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "jquery.terminal@0.11.11",
  "_id": "jquery.terminal@0.11.11",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/jquery.terminal",
  "_nodeVersion": "4.2.6",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-16-east.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/jquery.terminal-0.11.11.tgz_1475868856610_0.3736777463927865"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "jcubic",
    "email": "jcubic@onet.pl"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.5.2",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "jquery.terminal@0.11.11",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "jquery.terminal",
    "name": "jquery.terminal",
    "rawSpec": "0.11.11",
    "spec": "0.11.11",
    "type": "version"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery.terminal/-/jquery.terminal-0.11.11.tgz",
  "_shasum": "eaeed2f8f305ac0477d71ef492e7d98d6064d812",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "jquery.terminal@0.11.11",
  "_where": "/home/giovanni/Projects/Private/site",
  "author": {
    "name": "Jakub Jankiewicz",
    "email": "jcubic@onet.pl",
    "url": "http://jakub.jankiewi.cz"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "description": "jQuery Terminal Emulator is a plugin for creating command line interpreters in your applications.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "istanbul": "^0.4.3",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.14.5",
    "jsdom": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "eaeed2f8f305ac0477d71ef492e7d98d6064d812",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery.terminal/-/jquery.terminal-0.11.11.tgz"
  },
  "gitHead": "0f2e55a6501d96aa17d42e4fcc071fab906309d8",
  "homepage": "http://terminal.jcubic.pl",
  "keywords": [
    "terminal",
    "emulator",
    "prompt",
    "console",
    "keyboard",
    "type",
    "rpc",
    "input",
    "ui"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "js/jquery.terminal-0.11.11.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "jcubic",
      "email": "jcubic@onet.pl"
    }
  ],
  "name": "jquery.terminal",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal.git"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "version": "0.11.11"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I solved my problem by slightly modifying my Webpack configuration.
As suggested here ([Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)), I added a jquery alias.
In the example provided the alias is statically specified and it didn't work for me.
I switched to a dynamic value and that solved the problem.

Here it is the snippet:

```js
alias: {
      'jquery': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'jquery'))
     },
```

Comment: This is the thing that helped me. I was using `jquery/src/jquery` as an alias, but few old jquery plugins have dependencies in their `package.json` and this alias matches the wrong directory. For example: `some-jquery-plugin/node_modules/jquery/src/jquery` when the plugin has jQuery as a dependency. With  `jquery/src/jquery` as an alias, I had two different version of jQuery in my vendor.js because the old jQuery plugin expected anything after jQuery 1.0.0 and yarn/npm did download jQuery 3 while my project required older version 1.12.4

Comment: I was facing this problem when using three jquery plugins in my project (jquery-asScrollable, jquery-asScrollbar and jquery-asHoverScroll) and this answer pointed me in the right direction. In my case, the static alias `jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"` solved my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been looking for this guidance for over a day. I'm bundling a third party bootstrap 4 theme with a long list of vendor dependencies and it's own gulp-webpack task. After noticing a lot of inconsistent success with varying plugins - mostly centered around jquery - I've found it difficult to determine if each module is referencing the same jquery dependency. This technique immediately worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, for the `yarn` package manager, is to force using the library dependency of your main application. By specifying the [`resolutions`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in your `package.json`, it can be used to prevent downloading of differing versions of `sub-dependencies`. Other than your what your application uses.

> You should **not** use this solution if your package is *publicly redistributed*.

**Issue**

If for example your application depends on`"jquery": "~1.12.0"` and `jquery-plugin` which includes its own `dependencies: { "jquery": ">=1.9" }`. Assuming the latest version of jquery is 3.4.1, running `yarn install` will download a directory structure like.

```
node_modules
    jquery@1.12.4
    jquery-plugin
        node_modules
             jquery@3.4.1
```

```
//app.js
const $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-plugin');
console.log(typeof $.fn.plugin); //undefined
```

**Solution**

Add a `resolutions` field to your `package.json` file and define your version overrides.

*package.json*

**Force *ALL* sub-dependencies to use jQuery ~1.12.0**

```
{
    "name": "project-name",
     "dependencies": {
         "jquery": "~1.12.0",
         "jquery-plugin": "*"
     },
     "resolutions": {
         "jquery": "~1.12.0"
     }
}
```

or **Force *jquery-plugin* to use jQuery ~1.12.0**

```
{
    "name": "project-name",
     "dependencies": {
         "jquery": "~1.12.0",
         "jquery-plugin": "*"
     },
     "resolutions": {
         "jquery-plugin/jquery": "~1.12.0"
     }
}
```

Then run `yarn install`.

**Result** the duplicate jquery sub-dependencies are removed.

```
node_modules
    jquery@1.12.4
    jquery-plugin
```

```
//app.js
const $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-plugin');
console.log(typeof $.fn.plugin); //function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with jquery.terminal, but telling plugins explicitly how to load jQuery may help. I've had to do this for several plugins for similar issues.

```
    loaders: [{
        test: /jquery.terminal.+\.(js)$/,
        loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Quotidian, I have just solved the issue though!.
I'm about to post an answer.