# How to use select2 with webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, jquery-select2

I've downloaded `select2` as node module by:

```
npm install select2
```

and included it in my `app.js`:

```
require('select2')($);
```

---

When I run `webpack` there are no errors, but when I open the app I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object(…)
```

coming from `select2.js`:

```
S2.define('select2/core',[
  'jquery',
  './options',
  './utils',
  './keys'
], function ($, Options, Utils, KEYS) {
(...)
}
```

Does it happen because module wrapper for `select2` works only with AMD and is incompatible with CommonJS?

Answer (score 2):

Where do you see this is how to use select2? As far as I can see from glancing at the project, you need `jquery` installed as a dep but then it will be [automatically required](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/dist/js/select2.js#L20).

Looking at the signature of the exported function it looks like it might take a jQuery element and options: https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/dist/js/select2.js#L5052

However after importing it, it should just be attached to jQuery as a plugin, so I'd think that `$('.some-element').select2([options]);` would also work.

So did you simply try `require('select2')` (and `npm i jquery --save` if you haven't)?

Comment: Of course I had jquery, I thought it was too obvious to mention that. The problem was that some jquery plugins are wrapped in UMD which does some quirky checks if I use AMD, CommonJS or none, and this check breaks in Webpack, because Webpack supports both, so UMD wrapper assumes I use AMD even though I use commonJS. There is a hacky [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) for this in accepted answer at #4.

Answer (score 1):

if someone looking for this now just doing require('select') is not going to attache it jquery you have to `require('select2')();` then you can call

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.select2').select2()
})
```

then It will work. now I have tested this with electron js. it's working!

in my doc, this is how I import everything first jquery then select2

```
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
  require('select2')();
```