# Import jQuery Plugin. Angular 2 & Webpack

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack

This is turning out to be more frustrating than I expected.

I've figured out how to include things like jQuery and bootstrap in my Webpack build process. But one of the 3rd party angular directives I've added require a specific jQuery plugin to be available on the global $ scope... for the life of me I cant find a simple clear example of how to do this.

**This is the error code I keep getting:**

> Error: Error in ./SomeComponent class SomeComponent
>   - inline template:5:32 caused by: $(...).selectize is not a function

I've seen examples of using script-loader, expose-loader, using resolve with an alias set, I've tried them all... but I don't seem to be having much luck as I'm new to Webpack, and I've probably managed to confuse myself more than anything in the last 2 days. I think I'm mixing different solutions, which might be adding to the chaos.

I've read through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack?noredirect=1&lq=1) a few times, and it only explains how to load, jQuery itself... but not a jQuery plugin.

(some code excluded for brevity)

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /bootstrap-sass[\/\\]assets[\/\\]javascripts[\/\\]/,
        use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('selectize'),
        use: 'expose-loader?$!expose?selectize'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jquery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      jQuery:"jquery"
    }),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'selectize': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        '../selectize/dist/js/selectize.min.js'
      )
    },
    extensions: [
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    vendor: [
       ..
    ],
    main: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
  }
};
```

**app.ts**

```
import 'script-loader!selectize';
```

**Thus my question:**

How do I load a 3rd party jQuery plugin in an Angular 2 application making use of a Webpack 2 module loader / build process.

Comment: Isn't this a situation where you might want to look for a non-jquery, angular2-specific library that solves the same problem?

Comment: @jellymann. Yes and no... The issue is pertaining to importing 3rd party libs & their dependencies. Even if I had been able to get past this by going "angular-only". I'd still need to at some stage figure out how to serve/bundle/provide 3rd party dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to partially solve this using [alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)

**webpack.config.js**

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      selectize$: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/selectize'),
      // this can also be a path to an actual js file if you so choose
    }
  },
```

The above allows you to do this within whichever component you're working in:

```
import 'selectize';
```

then this within your template markup for the component:

```
<ng-selectize [config]="config" [options]="options"></ng-selectize>
```

The only problem I still have is how to serve the stylesheets in a similair fashion / include them in my vendor CSS bundle "automagically". For the time being I've copied the styles across, but will update this answer once I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

In our senario we had a external js file that needed to be added to the global scope. It wasn't in an npm package so we just included it directly.
We achieved this as follows:

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
  ...
    new ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
  ...
]
```

**main.browser.ts**

P.S. `main.browser.ts` is a webpack entrypoint

```
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');
require('../path_to_asset/selectize/dist/js/selectize.min.js');
```

We have a specific folder for all our assets like images, external js, etc.