# Using jquery-csv with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jquery-csv

I am using [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) as part of my project.

Currently I'm just loading the script in separately, but how do I use it with webpack?

Or perhaps there are better options for reading CSV files these days? All I want to do is grab a CSV file and turn it into an array of objects.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) about the general approach to using jQuery plugins, but I have to say, I'm baffled by it.

NB: I'm also using jQuery and Select2 (which has a jQuery dependency) in my project, and at the moment I'm not using webpack to load those.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning it to the aliases:

- jQuery.csv
- $.csv

jQuery-csv just attaches a new sub-namespace to the existing jQuery namespace.