# How to webpack a npm module?

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack

I want to run the simpleWeather jQuery Plugin in the browser by using the npm module. I heard that I need to use a bundler, so I installed Webpack.

This is the folder structure:

- Weather

  - js

    - index.js
  - node_modules

    - jquery
    - simpleweather
  - index.html
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>simpleWeather.minimum.js</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="weather"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Austin, TX',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</p>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
  }
}
```

This does not work in the browser, I guess, I need to configure Webpack in some different way.

What do I need to do?

Comment: suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your node package dependencies [jquery, simpleweather]  in index.js and do webpack build to generate bundle.js

Now loading jQuery in webpack is a bit tricky, so so can refer this answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/1681972

Comment: How do I import the package dependencies?