# $ is not defined within a .js.erb view using Webpack 2 in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, erb

I'm migrating from assets pipeline to Webpack 2 in a Rails 4 app. Everything seems to work fine, except for the JS code using jQuery within a **.js.erb** view.

The content of the *webpack.config.js* is as follows (omitted code for fingerprinting and compression):

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const jsOutputTemplate = 'javascripts/[name].js'
const cssOutputTemplate = 'stylesheets/[name].css'

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '/app/assets'),
  entry: {
    application: ['./javascripts/application.js', './stylesheets/application.scss']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: jsOutputTemplate
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader'])
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'])
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|svg)$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=/images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.erb$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: 'rails-erb-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: cssOutputTemplate,
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      '$': 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'jquery': 'jquery',
      'window.jquery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

The *jQuery* library (and others related) is required within *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* as follows:

```
require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
require('jquery-ujs');
require('jquery-datepicker');
```

As you can see, I've used the **rails-erb-loader** for *.erb* files but it doesn't work as I might have expected. When the *.js.erb* file is rendered, I always receive next error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

The code within this file is nothing fancy, only includes some JS calling jQuery's $ function:

```
let $messagesArea = $('#js-attachments-messages');
```

However, within console the $ is defined when I print it, even using a *debugger* at the beginning of the *.js.erb*:

```
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

I've included all the possible combinations I've came up to define the jQuery in the plugins section of *webpack.config.js*:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  '$': 'jquery',
  'window.$': 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'jquery': 'jquery',
  'window.jquery': 'jquery'
})
```

Is there any configuration I have not taken into account?

Any help would be appreciated to resolve this problem.

**UPDATE**

The content of *package.json* is as follows:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-datepicker": "^1.11.5",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    // ...
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've uploaded a sample app reproducing the error trying to remove a resource and then removing it from the page with jQuery.

[Sample app](https://github.com/backpackerhh/rails4-webpack2)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/1817690 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4258

Comment: ho have you tried to declare in your file somthing like declare var $ as any

Comment: None of those options worked. I've uploaded a sample app reproducing the error. The link is included in the post.

Comment: @backpackerhh , have you resolved the issue? Because I am facing the same issue?

Comment: @MubashirKamranSWEngineer The only way I've found to get ride of this error was using an explicit inline render of the file within the `.js.erb` file: `<%= render file: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %>`. I know it's not an ideal solution, but it works!

Answer (score 14):

I recently had a similar error due to the fact that jQuery required in Webpack is not exposed in the `view` folder of my app, therefore not visible in my *js.erb*  files.
This was solved by exposing jQuery globally adding the following 2 lines in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

> import $ from 'jquery';
>
> global.$ = jQuery;

Comment: thank you, this not only helps fix a similar issue but explains why.

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same issue with js.erb.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) could be enough, [as I proposed in a pull request](https://github.com/backpackerhh/rails4-webpack2-sample-app/pull/1) in the sample app linked above.

Summarizing it,

- Add `expose-loader`
- Expose jQuery to global object

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$'
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```