# $ is an empty object when bundled using webpack-2

Tags: jquery, requirejs, webpack-2, imports-loader, exports-loader

Recently, I have been thinking of moving our build process from `Grunt` to `webpack-2`. Our code is entirely written in AMD format using requirejs. For the purpose of the demo, I'll post the minimalistic version of our `index.js` file we are using.

Here's the link of jQuery-1.6.4 being used by committing the file and loaded via npm. Please excuse this for the time being. [jQuery-1.6.4](https://gist.github.com/softvar/7b05a085daa1dab196abe0d693f5e21d)

**`index.js`**

```
define(['jQuery', 'arrayUtils'], function ($, arrayUtils) {
  'use strict';
  console.log($); 
  console.log(arrayUtils);

});
```

Corresponding `require-config.js` file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    require.config({
        baseUrl: '../../src',
        waitSeconds: 0,
        paths: {
            jQuery: '/path to/jquery-1.6.4',
            urlUtils: '/path to/urlUtils',
            // ...
        },
        shim: {
            jQuery: {
                exports: '$'
            },
            urlUtils: {
                exports: 'urlUtils'
            },
            // ...
        }
    });
})();
```

I tried to use our AMD approach but want to bundle everything using webpack-2. I went through the docs and various blogs and came across the config which makes everything worked like a charm except the old-gold jQuery.

Here is the `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var UglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin;

// Import the plugin:
var path = require('path');
var env = require('yargs').argv.mode;
var outputFile;

var options = {
  target: 'this'
};
var libOptions = {
  name: 'heatmap-inject',
  version: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version)

};

var plugins = [];


if (env === 'build') {
  plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    minimize: true
  }));
}

// At the end of the file:
module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/library.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/webpack',
    library: 'library.js',
    filename: libOptions.name + '.js', // libOptions.name + (options.target ? '.' + options.target : '') + (env === 'build' ? '.min.js' : '.js')
    libraryTarget: options.target || 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /(\.js)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          plugins: []
        }
      }
    }, {
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /(\.js)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {}
      }
    }, { test: /jQuery/, loader: 'exports-loader?$'
    }, { test: /urlUtils/, loader: 'exports-loader?urlUtils'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
     'jQuery': 'heatmaps/vendor/jquery-1.6.4',
     'urlUtils': 'lib/heatmap/UrlUtils'
    },
    modules: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'src/bower_components',
      path.resolve('./src')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  plugins: plugins
};
```

The file which is generated by `webpack-2` throws an error that `$.fn` is not defined i.e. instead of `$` being a jQuery function it's a plain empty Object.
Though window.$ is defined and returns the right jQuery function but why not I'm getting the same result for `$`. In the case of AMD, I'm getting the correct result since `$` is in a closure and returns the 1.6.4 jQuery. Using webpack, it is behaving weirdly.

`!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [
    __webpack_require__(1),
    __webpack_require__(13)
], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function ($, urlUtils) { ... }`

**What other things I have tried:**

1. `{ test: /jQuery/, loader: 'expose-loader?$'`
2. `{ test: /jQuery/, loader: 'exports-loader?jQuery=jQuery,$=jQuery,this=>window'`
3. `{ test: /jQuery/, loader: 'exports-loader?this=>window'`
4. `{ test: /jQuery/, loader: 'expose-loader?$=jQuery'`

Can't use `externals` property as it pollutes the thw `window.jQuery` and as this library is injected/loaded on user's website, this will break things on the target source.

Please help me! I'm frustrated now with this weird jQuery thing.

Comment: how about https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/ ?

Answer (score 1):

This potentially is because [the version of jQuery you are using is before a jQuery AMD fix](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#amd). With jQuery 2.2.1 and 3.0, I ported a number of large AMD codebases over to ES Modules. The main stack overflow post I used to get through the jankiness of jQuery in a build env was [this very thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/1924257) by jhhns himself.

The crux of the solution, especially if you're using jQuery UI on top of jQuery, is to use the provide plugin and then have a "plugins" module that imports the particular modules you need. Especially if they have a particular order they need loaded in around the rest of the app in question.

With ES Modules (AMD works too):

```
// jquery-plugins.js
// import $ from 'jquery' is implicit because of the provide plugin
import 'jquery-ui'
import 'malihu-custom-scrollbar'
import 'datatables'
```

Importing this module first (or close to first) for all your dependencies will give you the jQuery namespaces you need later on.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I was using jQuery 1.9.1 (which is the last one with that amd bug) and jQuery UI. Adding `amd: { jQuery: true }` to webpack solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using jQuery 1.9.1 in my legacy code and going to bundle it with Webpack 4. I faced the similar issues.

After a full day struggling, by following @SamirAguiar's solution and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#amd, I figure out a workable way in my webpack config:

```
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery': 'jquery/jquery', // -> node_modules/jquery/jquery.js
      // ...
    },
  },
  amd: {
    jQuery: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery', // legacy code tend to use $ without requiring it
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

This works well with jquery-ui 1.10.3 and some other jQuery based plugins.