# string replace loader not working with webpack 3

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-3

I am using `webpack 3` & trying to use [string replace loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader).

This code use to work in webpack1.X

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /fileName\.js$/,
        loader: 'string-replace',
        query: {
          search: 'jQuery',
          replace: 'window.$'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried this as well:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /fileName\.js$/,
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            query: {
              search: 'jQuery',
              replace: 'window.$'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

What do I need to do to ensure this loader works in webpack 3. There are no errors but string is not getting replaced in the target file.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/2958224).. 

what you need is to implement #2

Comment: @harshes53: ProviderPlugin is not used for this purpose.

Comment: That is what you are trying to replace, whatever, give a try with regex-replace-loader.

Comment: @harshes53:providerPlugin creates global variables which are available across the application.

Comment: add one more prop `flags: 'g'` inside the query object..

Comment: or may be use `alias` option in webpack if that serves your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding `flags: 'g'` to the query option:

```
query: {
    search: 'jQuery',
    replace: 'window.$'
    flags: 'g'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Webpack 3 and Webpack 4 you can use the [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) to perform string replacement by pattern at compile time.

For Webpack 3, add the following code to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
   module: {
      loaders: [
         // configure replacements for file patterns
         { 
            test: /fileName\.js$/,
            loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                replacements: [
                    {
                        pattern: /jQuery/g,
                        replacement: function (_match, _p1, _offset, _string) {
                            return "window.$";
                        }
                    }
                ]})
            }
      ]
   },
   plugins: [
      // an instance of the plugin must be present
      new StringReplacePlugin()
   ]
}
```

For Webpack 4, the syntax is as follows:

```
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
   module: {
      rules: [{ 
         test: /fileName\.js$/,
         use: [{
            loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
               replacements: [{
                  pattern: /jQuery/g,
                  replacement: function (_match, _p1, _offset, _string) { return "window.$"; }
                  }]
            })
         }]
      }]
   },
   plugins: [
      new StringReplacePlugin()
   ]
}
```

Comment: I wasted almost 1h trying to figure it out why `string-replace-loader` didn't work with RegExp on my end before finding this solution..webpack is a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

WebPack 2 changed how configuration must be passed to a loader. So you can try (I've not tested this):

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /fileName\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'string-replace',
      options: {
        query: {
          search: 'jQuery',
          replace: 'window.$'
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

**Or** you can try this string replace loader as it seems to be have been written for WebPack 2.
https://github.com/dmitrySheshko/replace-string-loader

**Or** you can write your own:
https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/

string-replace-loader.js

```
const { getOptions } = require('loader-utils');

module.exports = function(source) {
  const options = getOptions(this);
  return source.replace(options.replace, options.with);
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /fileName\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: resolve(__dirname, './string-replace-loader.js'),
      options: {
        replace: /jQuery/gi,
        with: 'window.$'
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug in pattern-replace-loader.
It uses String.proototype.replace() method and it only replaces first entry of the pattern.

Use of flags: 'g' forces it to use RegEx and replace all entries in the file.
See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp