# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have to use **bootstrap** with **reactjs** and when i try to import Bootstrap.js it gives me error

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Here is my import statements (I tried following)

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery'; //I installed jquery using npm
import '@shopify/polaris/jquery'; //I put jquery.js file 
import '@shopify/polaris/bootstrap';
```

Nothing is seems to work here.

Comment: I think you would need to add jquery to your html file

Comment: Adding to html file file, removed the error for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your HTML file:

```
<html>
      <head>

           ..................
           ..................
           ..................
      </head>

      <body>
           ..................
           <script src="jquery.js"></script> // <<<<<< you missing import jquery here
           <script src="bootstrap.js"></script> // <<<<<<< you have this one
           ..................
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) as well as an alternative. It has all elements of the Bootstrap plus it blends well with ReactJS elements.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requires jquery to be available on the global object. Try the below -

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min');
```

I have verified it for bootstrap@3.3.7 and jquery@2.2.4.

Ref - [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5542#issuecomment-432298925)