# Integrating Auth0 with a cordova jQuery mobile app

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, auth0

I am trying to integrate Auth0 authentication with my already made cordova mobile app. I set up the client and was following the [quick start](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/cordova) guide from auth0. The problem I am facing is that the guide does not seem to be suitable for a jQuery app because it uses **require** and in the end builds a module. I am not sure how to do this using jQuery, since all other js files I have are inside `www/js` folder and I do not know how to import `node_modules` inside my app.

```
var Auth0 = require('auth0-js');
var Auth0Cordova = require('@auth0/cordova');
....
....
module.exports = App;
```

1. Can anyone tell me how can I do this without making much
   modification to my current app.
2. If not possible to set this up with jQuery, what other ways are
   there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are trying to use jQuery. But the easiest option is simply to add the jQuery dependency to your `js` folder, and reference using the usual `script` header in `index.html`.

Couple of resources for points [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/apache_cordova_and_jquery?lang=en) and if wishing to use an npm module then see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-jquery). This is doing something similar, adding the needed js dependencies to the `js`folder, and then updating `index.html` to reference to those js dependencies.

Finally, it is possible to extend webpack to reference jQuery - see an answer I posted separately on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34354301/1882064).

Comment: maybe my question is not clear enough but the problem is not using jquery but how to use external modules in the front-end. I used browserify to generate one consolidated js file with all the dependencies. I put the require() in my main app.js So now my app.js contains my own code plus all the code from require() but what has happened is that my global variables in app.js have lost the global scope. I am not sure how to get back the global scope for my own variables.

Comment: ok, this has nothing to do with Auth0, and more to do with your build system. Would google / search SOF for browserify related questions and global scope.