# jQuery is not defined: webpack +Angular 4+ Asp Core template

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I have a project generated from VS 2017  Angular 4 +Asp Core template
and I want to use a jQuery plugin so I need to import jQuery,in my .ts file I've used:

```
declare var $: any;
```

in webpack.config.vendor.js I have

```
plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }),
```

but in console I got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to import jquery with angular-cli. Edit your angular-cli.json file.

Find script array and add jquery.

```
     "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link below to install jquery.

https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to

After that you need to add :

```
 declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

in your app.component.ts to be available for all your application.

Comment: Hi,I've done installation but have no angular-cli.json file,also on: declare const $: JQueryStatic; I got : Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.thanks

Comment: Do you use angular cli ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: seems that jquery is imported with  import * as $ from 'jquery'; but it gives me errors on my plugin :    $(this.el.nativeElement).find('#passw').keyboard({   
 (TS) Property 'keyboard' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

Comment: You can cast it to any... (<any>$(this.el.nativeElement).find('#passw')).keyboard({})

Comment: Error is gone but my plugin doesn't work,it is mottie virtual keyboard and is not shown.no error in console

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I don't have any angular-cli.json file, and when I try to do this:  import * as $ from 'jquery'; I get an error saying: Module ''jquery'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct. Has anybody found a solution to this?