# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).modal is not a function

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am trying to open bootstrap modal but its not working in fullcalendar angular 2.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        (<any>$('#myModal33')).modal('show');
        $('#click_date').val(date._d);
      }
```

I get:

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery**(...).modal is not a function

If I remove this `import * as $ from 'jquery';` then the modal is working, but I need jQuery as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just change:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

as:

```
import * as $AB from 'jquery';
```

this solved my problem. now its work like vroom vroom.... yeheeeee.....

Comment: Hey this works really well, but do you know why we have to do this?

Comment: Not sure what exactly it does, but SOLVES the issue!! Thanks!

Comment: jaja, amazing...it works... really, really thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question has been answered.
[Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack).

Use the ProvidePlugin to inject implicit globals

Most legacy modules rely on the presence of specific globals, like jQuery plugins do on $ or jQuery. In this scenario you can configure webpack, to prepend var $ = require("jquery") everytime it encounters the global $ identifier.

**custom.typings.d.ts** might be needed to prevent typescript errors.

You could install "@types/jquery" and this file might not be needed.

```
declare var $: any;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

...

plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does work but here's my thought why the `$AB` works, but not the `$`.

From the `@types/jquery` page, it says that the package contains global values `$, Symbol and jQuery`. In this case, you need to import everything from the package but not overriding the three variables themselves.

So, just add the below line into your `app.module.ts` and you will be able to use the `$` mark throughout your application.

```
import * as AnythingThatIsNotDollarSignOrSymbolOrjQuery from "jquery"
```