# Webpack - _ is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, underscore.js

When I run webpack, `_` returns as undefined on window: `window._ ::: Error: _ is not defined`. I thought that putting `_` inside the plugins will expose it to `window`. Is my understanding incorrect?

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const plugins = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    _: "underscore"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main/app/components/main.module.js',
        vendor: [
            'jquery',
            'underscore'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: './src/main/resources/dist/app/scripts/[name].bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [plugins],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

Comment: is $ undefined?

Comment: $ is defined which is the strange part

Comment: Don't you need a `resolve` block to tell Webpack **where** to find `jquery` and `underscore`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: providePlugin doesn't expose libs to the window - it provides access to those libs in the context of other modules in the webpack bundle

Comment: can use the expose-loader to add to window: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add it as a global variable? 
Try adding this to your .ts / .js file:

`window['_'] = require('underscore');`

Answer (score 1):

`providePlugin` is used to make libraries available in the context of other modules in the webpack bundle. For example, this usage of `providePlugin`:

```
const plugins = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  _: "underscore"
});
```

will allow access to jquery lib in `./src/main/app/components/main.module.js` via the `$` variable.

If you want to expose jquery to the window as `window.$`, you can either use webpack's [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader), or simply update the window in your entry file (main.module.js):

```
window.$ = $; //$ is defined via providePlugin
window._ = _; //_ is defined via providePlugin
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the underscore.js in your index file?

`<script src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js'></script>`