# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Webpack and embedded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webpack, webpack-2

I am using webpack to create a *.js bundle

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        site: [
            './wwwroot/js/site.js',
            './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            './Scripts/jquery.global.js',
            './node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
            './node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js',
            './node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js',
            './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/bundle.css'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        })
    ]
};
```

Then in the `_Layout.cshtml` I have the following code:

```
 ...

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - MVC_Movie</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/dist/bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="">
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            //Ask ASP.NET what culture we prefer, because we stuck it in a meta tag
            var data = $("meta[name='accept-language']").attr("content")
            //Tell jQuery to figure it out also on the client side.
            $.global.preferCulture(data);
            //Tell the validator, for example,
            // that we want numbers parsed a certain way!
            $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
                if ($.global.parseFloat(value)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I don't get any errors to generate the `bundle.js` file looks fine, but the  section at the bottom of the  `_Layout.cshtml` raises an exception

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I thought by defining in the `webpack.config.js` the plugin section the symbol `$` would be recognized:

```
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/bundle.css'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        })
    ]
```

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution it seems to work is to expose the jQuery module outside of the webpack bundle.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: 'css-loader'
            })
        },
        {
            // Exposes jQuery for use outside Webpack build
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'jQuery'
            }, {
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '$'
            }]
        }
    ]
},
```

Solution found here: [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) @harlemsquirrel

Answer (score 0):

attach jquery.js file before JS Bundle

Comment: If you check my code, you will see the jquery.js file is added into the bundle.

Comment: it happens bundle load all JS files as one so other files use "$" that's why  $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Based on the long discussion [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/108), it looks like you need to resolve jquery module with a alias as `$` or `jQuery` rather than defining it as a plugin.

here is the webpack config for that:

```
 resolve : {
    alias: {
        jquery: "./vendor/jquery/jquery.js",
    }
},
```

WebPack documentation [page](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx)

Comment: Actually the bundle is generated without error when using the plugin. I have tried using the alias, but didn't help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack Trying to implement the options here also didn't work.

Comment: are you saying your getting same error with alias ?

Comment: yes, I get the same error of undefined. I have found a solution using the expose-loader. I will post the answer, in case another solution fits it better.