# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

i am using webpack 4 for js bundling.jquery is working inside webpacked files.But not working inside html file.It showing below error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

webpack.config.js

```
 plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename:'css/app.bundle.css'}),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",  
            jQuery: "jquery" 
        })
    ],
```

and i tried to call jquery inside index.html file,but i am getting undefind error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("here");
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like your jquery code is unable to find jquery.js file. Make sure that it gets loaded before your jquery code takes place on the page.

Comment: Did you try `npm install jquery --save` and  `npm update` ?

Comment: Tried....jquery working inside entry file(bundled file)

Comment: i got the solution..thank you all
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550247/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-webpack-and-embedded-script?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

There are many cases to make the error message. These are some:

1/. jQuery is not installed. Fix: `npm i jquery`

2/. $ refers to jQuery but the scope is not global.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",  
    jQuery: "jquery" 
})
```

By using this way, we define 2 *global* variables with the names `$` and `jQuery` which refer to jquery. So,

Q: Where is the scope of that *global*?

A: Inside `bundle.js` file or any js file which is refered in `webpack.config.js` file:

```
entry: {
    'bundle.js': ['./assets/js/site', './assets/sdk/js/app']
}
```

In the file `site.js` and `app.js`, `$` and `jQuery` are 2 global variables.

Every js file else cannot use `$` and `jQuery` because of `not defined`.

Q: I just want to compile the 2 files `site.js` and `app.js` to the file `bundle.js`. But I still want to use jquery in any `.html/.php/.cshtml...` file(s), how can I do that?

A: Make jquery is global using `window` object. Like this:

`site.js`:

```
(function (global) {
    // $ and jQuery are function here...
    global.$ = $;
    global.jQuery = jQuery;
}(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this));
```

Then,

```
<!-- bundle.js contains the code which makes $ refers to jquery, so we need to import it first -->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  // it should work
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("here");
  });
</script>
```

In other js files, we can use this way too. Or using 'require':

`test.js`:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

**Notice:** In many cases, `window` may NOT an object in webpack, that why we need the line:

```
typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this
```

If you just write:

```
window.$ = $;
```

It may throw an error message like this:

> window is not defined

Hope this helps!