# how to embed Jquery and Jquery plugin library in WebPack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, webpack

I am now using webpack with angular and typescript structure.
I have a problem about emebed jquery and jquery.flipster in the project.

This is my folder structure
[image]

And this is my webpack.config.js
[image]

how to embed this jquery.flipster in the html and config?

i was trying to include jquery.flipster for animation.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.flipster

After npm install jquery.flipster, i cannot find  jquery.flipster in "wwwroot" folder,
so that i cannot embed jquery.flipster.

Please advice.

Comment: If you installed it using `npm`, it'll be in your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: @fubar but how to embed those 
<script language="JavaScript" src="../jquery.flipster.js"></script>


what's the path?

Comment: Unless you can post the project directory structure, no-one is going to be able to tell you that. Find the `node_modules` directory, and write a relative path from your HTML view to that directory.

Comment: @fubar
updated with screen capture. thanks

Comment: Your `node_modules` directory is typically at the same level as your `package.json`. With that being the case for you (I cannot see it in your screenshot), the directory is outside of your webroot, and therefore (assuming correct server configuration), inaccessible to the web. I would therefore recommend that you include and bundle the jQuery plugin into your `webpack` config. There are loads of answers on Stackoverflow already that show how to do this. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack