# React - '$' is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a React Redux application. Im adding materialize as the CSS framework, but materialize requires jquery. So i installed Jquery and added it to my project via npm. If i import jquery like so

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

No errors are thrown and im able to use it. But only on that component. So i added the wepback plug so i can call $ anymore in my react application. However, when i do this as described on webpacks [website](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), it get the following error.

```
Line 13:  '$' is not defined
```

Any ideas on why this is ?

app.js

```
import React  from 'react';
import '../styles/index.css';
import Header from './header/Header';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('Application ready');
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    }
    render = () => (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
    alias: {

  // Support React Native Web
  // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
  'react-native': 'react-native-web',
  jquery: "jquery/src/jquery" // What i added 
  // $: "jquery/src/jquery" 
},
```

jquery is in the node_modules folder, from the npm install, i didnt add it to any other location.

Comment: you should use material-ui: http://www.material-ui.com/#/ it's a material design impl for react.

Comment: Is related with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack/47333184#47333184

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>You've aliased jQuery to the global variable `jQuery`, not `$` -  do `alias: { $: 'jquery' }`.</strike>

Wrong, this isn't what `alias` is for, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Global variables in (browser) JS are really properties of `window`. So at the start of your script you could do

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
```

and it'd be available globally after that. Including jQuery in its own `<script>` tag would do the same thing. But these are both un-webpack, a bit naughty, not modular. The 'correct' thing to do is `import $ from 'jquery'` in every file where you need it. Yeah this will be tedious if you need it in a lot of places, but it means you know where you need jQuery and where you don't, and if you removed all the components that used jQuery, jQuery would disappear as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add on for Gatsby.js you can `npm i jquery` and then import jquery in `gatsby-browser.js`.

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min';
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.min'; // for navbar animation
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
```

`import $ from 'jquery';` in the relevant files will then detect $