# How to import jquery in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with jquery when i using it on webpack.
My code:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
            // './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/fs.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/google-adsense.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery.menu-aim.min.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js',
        ],
        app: './src/main/assets/js/desktop/app.js',
        mobile: './src/main/assets/js/mobile/app.js',
        touch: './src/main/assets/js/touch/app.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$'
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['src/main/webapp/assets']),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common' // Specify the common bundle's name.
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/,
            sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/js')
    }
};
```

When above code compiles , console throws this error

**vendor.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at vendor.js:1**

And when i try to use this

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

It throws

```
vendor.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.231 (vendor.js:1)
    at o (common.js:1)
    at Object.228 (vendor.js:1)
    at o (common.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (common.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
```

And i using jquery in my core js file `import $ from 'jquery'`.
What did i do wrong ? any help ? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

Comment: @JordiCastilla above link doesn't fix my problem. I am still on this :(. Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you check all post?? IMHO seems you're missing `npm i jquery --save` or some other small part defined in the linked question

Comment: Yes, i tried `npm install jquery --save` and `npm update` etc

Comment: How are you _using_ jQuery?

Comment: @AluanHaddad i didn't understand your question so well i am sorry. But i think i am using jquery like in my core js file `import $ from 'jquery'`.

Comment: That (`import $ from 'jquery';`) is what I wanted to know thanks. Add it to your question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad please suggest me edited version :) thank you.

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene no need, that is the proper and correct import syntax. The issue is likely in your configuration. You say that you've ran `npm i jquery`, however, you are explicitly bundling `'./src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'`. Having a third party library in your application folder is almost certain to cause problems. Additionally, you like 3 other plugins that do something jQuery related. Just try the simple case (no special exclude, no external, no expose) first.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i thought it was causing jquery minified version and i update `3.3.1.min.js` to `3.3.1.js` and rebuild and still don't work as you said i need to don't use exclude ? or something different ?

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene that is not the point. Someone asked you if you installed it with npm, you said yes but look at your config. You are either not bundling that installed version or you are bundling multiple versions!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So there are few themes in your `webpack.config.js`, some of which conflict. Just going to list them so I can better understand what I think you are trying to achieve.

**Theme 1**

You have an entry called `vendor` that is clearly referencing a minified jQuery library you have presumably downloaded and placed in the directory specified.

**Theme 2**

You also have an `expose-loader` that is essential exposing the `jquery` library from its `node_modules` probably listed in the `dependencies` of your `package.json`.

This makes the `jquery` in the `node_modules` available as `$` and `jQuery` in the global scope of the page where your bundle is included.

**Theme 3**

You also have included the `ProvidePlugin` with configuration for jQuery.

The `ProvidePlugin` is supposed to inject dependencies into the scope of your module code, meaning you do not need to have `import $ from 'jquery'` instead `$` and `jQuery` will already be available in all of your modules.

**Conclusion**

From what I have gathered ***I think*** you're trying to bundle jQuery from the static file at `./src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` in a vendor bundle.

You are then trying to expose the libraries in the vendor bundle to the global scope (jQuery).

Then also have your application code able to import jQuery from what is made available by the vendor bundle in the global scope.

**Answer**

So if that is what you are doing you need to do the following things.

Firstly, check in your `package.json` files `dependencies` for `jquery`. If its there you want to remove it, there's no need for it if you're going to use your `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` file instead to provide jQuery to your application.

Secondly, change your `test` of the `expose-loader` to trigger when it sees your `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` file in your entries, not resolve it from the `jquery` dependency from your `node_modules`.

This regex pattern should do the trick.

```
{
  test: /jquery.+\.js$/,
  use: [{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
  },{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: '$'
  }]
}
```

Thirdly, remove the `ProvidePlugin` if you're going to import the library explicitly with `import $ from 'jquery'` you do not need it.

Lastly, you need to tell webpack when it sees an import for `jquery` it can resolve this from `window.jQuery` in the global scope. You can do this with the externals configuration you already referenced.

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

With all these changes you should end up with a `webpack.config.js` file that looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
            // './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/fs.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/google-adsense.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery.menu-aim.min.js',
            './src/main/webapp/js/vendor/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js',
        ],
        app: './src/main/assets/js/desktop/app.js',
        mobile: './src/main/assets/js/mobile/app.js',
        touch: './src/main/assets/js/touch/app.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /jquery.+\.js$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'jQuery'
                },{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: '$'
                }]
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['src/main/webapp/assets']),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common' // Specify the common bundle's name.
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/,
            sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/js')
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
};
```

I hope that does not just give you the answer but enough explanation as to where you were going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i am understand what i am exactly doing wrong. This is fixed my problem ! :)

Comment: Great glad it helped! :)

Comment: One has to do all this just to import jQuery into ones Rails app now? What the hell?

Comment: @MarkBoulder there are many ways to skin a cat. All of them wrong ;)

Comment: You may need to use this instead: `{loader: "expose-loader", options: { exposes: ["$", "jQuery"] }}` as the only item in `use` under `test: /jquery.+\.js$/`. See https://github.com/dao42/rails-template/issues/29