# $('#load') cause: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have next html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
     
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning"
  onclick='debugger;lazy_load( $("#load") )'
>Primary</button>

<div id="load">
  <div data-lazy-load="ajax/data-ajax.json">Loading...</div>
  <div data-lazy-load="ajax/data-ajax.html">Loading...</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import { ajax_query } from "../common/ajax";

export function lazy_load( container ) {
  container ||=  $('#load');
  ...
}
```

`webpack.config.js` has:

```
  plugins: config.scripts.isUseJquery
    ? [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          jQuery: "jquery",
          jquery: "jquery",
          $: "jquery",
          "window.jQuery": "jquery",
          "window.jquery": "jquery",
          "window.$": "jquery",
        }),
      ]
    : [],
};
```

When I open this page I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
near this code `lazy_load( $("#load") )`.

When I remove parameter `$("#load")` then same code inside `lazy_load` works fine.

Even when script execution stop at `debugger`, I can run `$("#load")` at console without any error!

**Why `onclick='lazy_load( $("#load") )'` does not work?**

**UPD**
[image]

When I replace onclick: `onclick='lazy_load()'`
[image]

Comment: You typically see this when jQuery is not present/linked to.

Comment: @RobMoll: jQuery is linked. You can see that $('#load') is working fine inside `lazy_load` function and at console. Why `jQuery` is not linked to main page?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(jQuery);`? Is that available? Maybe your code loads before jQuery?

Comment: @PeterKrebs: it is available from inside `lazy_load` but not from main page (see updated question)

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. I'll post a suggestion as an answer. May not be the solution but maybe it helps.

Comment: I would suggest not using `onclick` with modules. It's a bit like having a manual crank starter hooked up to a Ferrari. Instead, use `addEventListener` to attach the event listener with the appropriate scope.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: unfortunately modules does not know where event should be added. this knowledge belongs to the main page. So I expose $ (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

To make `$` global I must to expose it.

So I install `expose-loader` and adjust my `webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve("jquery"),
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: { exposes: [ '$', 'jQuery' ] },
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Notice: for webpack 5 there is different config format, so I install `expose-loader` version 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

When coding with modules, you should also import jQuery explicitly:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import { ajax_query } from "../common/ajax";

export function lazy_load( container ) {
  container ||=  $('#load');
  ...
}
```

Otherwise see more possible solutions here:
[How to import jQuery in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579518/how-to-import-jquery-in-webpack)

Comment: Following your link, `import $ from "jquery"` is not required because of `ProvidePlugin`. And as you can see from question at this module `$('#load')` works fine. The problem is with index.html which does not see $

Comment: Oh right, if you have that sure. Why don't you move that code to a module as well?

Comment: Because index.html know the ID of element to find, not the module

Comment: Seems I found solution, see answer below