# Typescript and Jquery import - $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, npm

I'm using typescript with jquery, but I keep getting

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Has anybody seen this before?

I'm compiling typescript to ES2017, then transpiling to ES5 using webpack.

```
//tsconfig
{
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",

        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "Output",
        "esModuleInterop": true

      }
    }
```

How jquery is being used

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
 var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
```

The browser sees jquery ($)
[image]

But then I get this

[image]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/iblrdv so there's something wrong with your jquery

Comment: is `jquery` the path of your JQuery Library?? you have to type the path of your JQuery library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution.  To use $ as a function, I had to import the default from the the jquery npm module.  With this import statement, it works.

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

I also had to turn this on in tsconfig.json

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports":  true
```

Comment: With this approach I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` * But I did not install jquery via `npm`, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing jQuery type definitions which are needed by typescript compiler. You need to install both jQuery and jQuery type definitions. If you are using `npm` to install packages, the below steps will work. (Otherwise make sure you have both the packages installed in your environment)

1.Install jQUery

```
npm install --save jquery
```

2.Install jQuery type definitions

```
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

Now, you can import jQuery in your code as below

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: No -- he is having a runtime error. Type declarations don't affect runtime code.