# How do I import jQuery Masonry using ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, npm-install, jquery-masonry

I am trying to use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonry-layout

As per install instruction I ran:

```
npm install masonry-layout --save
```

Then in my file,

```
import '../../../node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js'

$('.blog-posts-container').masonry({
    // options ...
    itemSelector: '.card-blog',
    columnWidth: 200
})
```

I'm trying to import the package in my file and run it, but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function
```

Im thinking there is something wrong with my import here. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am using webpack

Comment: Do you use any packager? Webpack, Rollup? Please add an appropriate tag to the question, that would help a lot.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Using Webpack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get this to work, you need to use [jQueryBridget](https://github.com/desandro/jquery-bridget) which makes jQuery plugin out of a constructor function.

Here's an example using the [imagesloaded plugin](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) to make sure masonry initializes after the images have loaded.

```
npm i -S jQueryBridget imagesLoaded
```

Then in `app.js` (or whatever):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';
import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';
import imagesLoaded from 'imagesloaded';

jQueryBridget('masonry', Masonry, $);
jQueryBridget( 'imagesLoaded', imagesLoaded, $ );

const $container = $('#masonry-grid');

$container.imagesLoaded(() => {
  $container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.item',
  });
});
```

The above should be bundled (using Webpack) into `bundle.js`.

And for the sake of completeness, here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Masonry Madness</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="masonry-grid">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/889/88940833.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/907/90775901.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/294/29489326.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/100/100656385.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/889/88940839.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/111/111773987.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/146/146371016.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/103/10313578.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/554/55473337.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/537/53727259.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/111/111246515.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clarifai-img/demo/461/46176355.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTH