# configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

my output of error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:    object { exprContextCritical?,
>   exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?,
>   noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?,
>   unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?,
>   unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?,
>   wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?,
>   strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }    -> Options
>   affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }

};


module.exports = config;
```

my webpack version:

```
webpack@4.1.1
```

Answer (score 404, accepted):

You should change `loaders` to `rules` in webpack 4:

change:

```
loaders
```

to:

```
rules
```

source: [Loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#example)

Example:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Is it a typo? It should be `rules` in webpack 4.

Comment: you should use rules in webpack 4.

Comment: change loaders to rules in webpack 4... in case it needed to be said again :/

Comment: You should explain in your answer that the reason for the change is webpack 4.

Answer (score 16):

Use `rules` in webpack 4 instead of `loaders`.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [migration utility](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/MIGRATE.md) to migrate your webpack config files, it worked for me.

The [migration documentation](https://webpack.js.org/migrate) is also useful.

Answer (score 3):

Above given answers are working but we can resolve this issue by changing webpack and webpack-dev-server version to

```
"webpack": "3.8.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4"
```

It can also solve the issue. Hope it will help.

Comment: I gave you an uptick. Only problem is that people want to up versions of frameworks and tools to get new features not go back to older versions just to ensure they don't have to change their config files. Perhaps taking the pain to change the config file to align with the new way the tool works is not bad. Unless that is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @Eniola, Yeah you are right. As I mentioned the S.M_Emamian answer is correct but my answer will work if someone agrees to work will the older version of webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Working for me below webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        '.src/index.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
          { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
          { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Webpack 5 and I removed below config from my webpack.config. It worked for me after removing.
It may help some other people who still facing error

> ```
>         {
>             test: /\.css$/,
>             use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
>         },
> ```