# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, webpack-dev-server

) I am getting this error: 
[image]

I installed versions  webpack@3.10.0 but then I reinstalled 2.3.0, (I thought it would help....)

Thank you in advance for your answer ;)

Comment: I'm getting that same exact error. No fix found yet, even after trying to install webpack-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. What you have to do is to install the `webpack-cli` package with the -D flag in the terminal:

```
npm install webpack-cli -D
```

After you have installed the package update the dependencies in the package.json:

```
npm update
```

Now you should be able to start the server.

If this is not the case and you run in a configuration error you may have to change also something in the package.json. For that follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370849/configuration-module-has-an-unknown-property-loaders).

Answer (score 2):

For those using webpack 5, replace webpack-dev-server command with webpack serve

Answer (score 0):

npm i -D webpack-cli

and then npm update solved the issue for me.