# Webpack build error. Invalid configuration object. Invalid target param

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-app-rewired

Have this code in config-overrides.js

```
const rewireReactHotLoader = require('react-app-rewire-hot-loader')

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config = rewireReactHotLoader(config, env)
  config.target = 'es2020'
  config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    hpscm: 'src/apps/hpscm',
    lut: 'src/apps/lut/src/apps/lut',
    shared: 'src/apps/lut/src/apps/shared',
    search: 'src/apps/search/src/apps/search',
    kbase: 'src/apps/kbase/src/apps/kbase',
    docflow: 'src/apps/docflow/src/apps/docflow',
  }

  return config
}
```

Got this error:

```
Failed to compile.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.target should be one of these:
   "web" | "webworker" | "node" | "async-node" | "node-webkit" | "electron-main" | "electron-renderer" | "electron-preload" | function
   -> Environment to build for
   Details:
    * configuration.target should be one of these:
      "web" | "webworker" | "node" | "async-node" | "node-webkit" | "electron-main" | "electron-renderer" | "electron-preload"
    * configuration.target should be an instance of function
```

Have also checked this question
[configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370849/configuration-module-has-an-unknown-property-loaders)

I don't have "loaders" in my config, only "rules". Couldn't find any solution. Have somebody also ran into this issue?

Comment: Target should be "web" or one of these other options. es2020 is not a target but rather a babel preset

Comment: But I found it here
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/

Comment: Are you using the same version of webpack as the documentation?

Comment: No, I'm using 4.41.2. Seems like I need to update a bunch of packages. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to update version of webpack to set target as es2020
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/