# Webpack how to import entire Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, bundle

How can I bundle together multiple JS Files? I know I can export functions or classes and import them in other files and webpack will bundle all of them together in one file. But what do i do if I want to import an entire file? Or a framework like Vue?

Comment: Seems duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack`

Comment: Do you want to import this file separately or do you want to include it in your bundle ?

Comment: I wanted to import them globally. that's the keyword I was missing. my questions were answered there. thank you @brk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)