# "$ is not defined" when using $ in view after requiring it in app.js

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have an app and want to use `Jquery` in script tags inside my views.

I've tried moving the imports and making sure the `app.js` with the require `jquery` is loaded BEFORE the other script does (with alerts, one right after the importation, one right before the jquery I want to use).

I guess I could make one file per view and change my `webpack` config and require each time `jquery`, but that would be bothersome.

`app.js`

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

`login.blade.php` (layout)

```php
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("jQuery loaded");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', "jQuery", "window.$", "jquery", "window.jquery"],
    'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js': ['Popper']
}).js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js', 'ressources/js/password.js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I expect an alert saying jQuery loaded but got an

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Why `try..catch`?

Comment: I'm logging it in case of

Comment: You're not logging anything

Comment: I thought it wasn't useful for the question to include it

Comment: The code in your question only shows that if you cannot load jQuery or Bootstrap, the problem is silently ignored. I would remove the `try..catch`

Comment: what is the value of window.$ after the error is shown? if you run `console.log($('').jquery)`, what happens?

Comment: `console.log($('').jquery)` returns the same error `$ is not defined` and for the value of `window.$` it is undefined. Yet `window.Popper` shows Popper.js

Comment: What about `jQuery().jquery`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: @MoshFeu `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: It actually seems to be working if I'm doing `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`. Gonna check if my functions work as expected and will come back.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've done `npm install` and `npm run dev`? Have you checked that you're not seeing a cached `app.js`? Have you looked in `app.js` to see if jQuery is actually in there?

Comment: @Joe I'm able to call jQuery in my app.js yes. Thanks for checking this. Is actually seems to be working fine with the global instead of window. For what reason, I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app.js requirement I changed

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

to

`global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`

If someone has the reason as to why this does work (and maybe why I shouldn't do that), I'd be happy to hear it.