# How do I solve this jQuery loading error in Smarty

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, smarty

I have some on page script that produces a constant `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.

The jQuery is loaded at the bottom of the html page just before the  tag. I have added a DOM listener so the code can wait for the JQuery load. Can you see anything wrong, code is bellow.

Webpack config:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
      })
```

**console.log 1 works, console.log 2 doesn't**

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

    console.log('DOM loaded and parsed 1'); // Works!

        if ($('.add-user').length) {
            const addUser = (callbackFunction) => {
                const data = {
                    signup_name: $('#signup-name').val(),
                    user_name: $('#user-name').val(),
                };

                console.log(data);
                callbackFunction();
                return data;
            }
        }
        console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed 2'); // Doesn't Work?
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that jQuery is not available due to Webpack settings.

After some research i found an answer that helped solve the error:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937798/10814553

Install expose-loader: `npm install expose-loader --save-dev`

and add this to webpack.config.js

```
module: {
        rules: [            
             {
              // Exposes jQuery for use outside Webpack build
              test: require.resolve('jquery'),
              use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'jQuery'
              },{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '$'
              }]
            }
        ]
}
```

and make sure you also added the plugin

```
plugins: [
    // Provides jQuery for other JS bundled with Webpack
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added jQuery `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
This could be in the HEAD or in the footer of the page, just make sure you load it before you try to call any other jQuery stuff.

If it still gives you error, try to add `var $ = jQuery`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the solution but can help you determine if the problem is coming because jQuery hasn't yet loaded or not, if the second console log still doesn't show up then the problem is related to something else.
I delayed the execution of the code by 5 seconds which is largely enough for jquery to load before your code gets executed

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

    console.log('DOM loaded and parsed 1'); // Works!
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (jQuery('.add-user').length>0) {
            const addUser = (callbackFunction) => {
                const data = {
                    signup_name: jQuery('#signup-name').val(),
                    user_name: jQuery('#user-name').val(),
                };

                console.log(data);
                callbackFunction();
                return data;
            }
        }
        console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed 2'); // Doesn't Work?
    },5000)
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Thanks or the help! Now it says: `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `

I wonder if it is related to webpack and how JQuery is added!

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })`