# How to import/load entire file to include in my bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to include an entire file into my bundle main.js?

ES6 can `import`/`export` functions and classes. But what if i want to include the whole content from another file into my bundle main.js? how to do it?

I came across the query on Stackoverflow: [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack).

I'm not sure about this question though. Those options given there seem to target *injecting implicit globals*, *configuring this*, *disabling AMD*, *to include large dists*. I don't think this is what i want.

Let's say i have two files in src directory
1- **rough.js**

```
const rgh = "qwerty"
```

2- **index.js**

```
import './rough.js' //something like this
console.log (rgh)
```

Now what i expect in bundle.js is

```
const rgh = "query";
console.log(rgh)
```

I just want all the content inside one of my file to get all transported to index.js for webpack to bundle them

Comment: What is the content of that file?

Comment: @IamL some statements, loops etc. I mean regardless of what the content is, what i s the way to load an entire content in the bundle?

Comment: wrap them inside a function and call that function on the when importing?

Comment: Why does that question not answer yours? There are [several valid approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/542251) there for your problem? The script loader plugin seems exactly what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing jQuery plugin dependency in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack)

Comment: @Liam in script-loader it is stated in the github pages that "It has a known issue of generating non-deterministic hashes (see #49, #56, #60). Do not use it." and it is also no longer maintained

Comment: What about the other 5 options?

Comment: @Liam the other five options seem to target ''injecting implicit globals", "configuring this", "disabling AMD", "to include large dists". I dont think this is what i want. I just want the context inside one of my file to get all transported to index.js for webpack to bundle them

Comment: Ok, you need to put all this into your question. Simply saying, I need this, here's a similar question, isn't very helpful. Explain why this question isn't helpful and what you need that's missing. To repeat, do this in the question, not here in comments

Comment: *I just want the context inside one of my file to get all transported to index.js* So you want to **inject implicit globals**, i.e. you want all the variables in your file to be implicitly available inside the global scope

Comment: @Liam the word "context" is a typo; i meant "content", i presume this is no different here. I edited my question as u suggested. And i dont just want variables to be available. It's just simple. I want the file to be appended in the bundle the same way it would be by using `<script>` 
element referencing the the file needed to be included before the `script` element referencing index.js or main.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203097/discussion-between-jake-and-liam).

Comment: I've got to prepare for a meeting, if I find time later I'll try and explain this to you.

Comment: @liam yeah ok. That will be a huge favour if i get this nailed. it already ate more than 24 hours

Comment: [This will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: i know about scope and closure. May be i'm missing some pieces. i'm try to figure out

Comment: What your expecting is wrong, look at my answer carefully, the `console.log` is wrapped in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica So what is the solution for my expected result? modularize my all unmodularize functions and variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Those options given there seem to target injecting implicit globals,
>   configuring this, disabling AMD, to include large dists. I don't think
>   this is what i want.

To understand this you need to understand what webpack is doing for you. Web pack takes a series of Javascript files (and more importantly their contents) and parses these into one file. That's what it does from a file point of view, but if you ignore the file and think about what it does from a code point of view, it takes each one of the imported **objects** and makes them available to other **objects** depending upon the rules you define in your code (using `import` and `export`). You can think of this from a closure point of view something like this:

if you have some code like:

```
import a from 'a.js';

export default b(){
    console.log(a.test());
}
```

This will be turned into something like, in one js file:

```js
var a = (function() {
    var testStr = "test";
    function test(){
        return testStr;
    }
    return {test:test};
})();

var b = (function(a) {
    console.log(a.test());
})(a);
```

So you can see that the **file** isn't really important. What's important is the scope. `b` can use `a` because it is injected into it's scope (In this instance as a IIFE).

In the above example `a` and `b` are in the **global scope** but `testStr` isn't.

So when your talking about "importing my file", you need to forget about that and think about what objects in that file you want to import how. Any variables "in that file" declared directly `var a = ....;` are in the global scope. So it sounds like what you want to do is [import the objects in that file into the **global scope**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989476/542251).

Comment: And now its making sense. Now I presume providePlugin is what i want

Comment: It still doesn't get me the result what i expect. I have added more details to what i expect in question. Added a bounty too

Answer (score -2):

you just need to import that file in main.js
like this way

[image]

Comment: in the main.js of dist or src? it would be more convenient if i add that in index.js and let the webpack load it. i hope u get my point

Comment: yes you can.

like this way
`code`
// ===compile our main.js file
mix.js('resources/assets/main.js', './')
 vendor bundle
    .extract(['vue', 'bootstrap-vue', 'animejs', 'axios'])