# materialize methods not recognized

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm using the materialize lib in my project. I initialize all elements at once:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min';
let main = require('./js/main');
let $ = require('jquery');

M.AutoInit();

main.init();
```

and that causes no errors. Then in main.js I'm trying to use it as in documentation:

```
$('.tabs').tabs("select","tab2");
```

But I receive the error

> TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

What am I forgetting about?

Comment: I see that you're including jQuery _after_ your custom script. Is that how it's loaded in the page?

Comment: why need jquery? there is a standalone method for it: 
https://materializecss.com/tabs.html

Comment: @isherwood not sure to be honest... the projects uses webpack in the way that I do not fully understand. Changing the order in the file does not change it though. I need to include jQuery in main.js as well (as it is not included generally) so maybe that is the same with materialize? The problem is that using that with `import` causes `ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: ./js/main.js` error. How to include and use it then it correctly in that case?

Comment: @Sysix I use jquery anyway, not for materialize only.

Comment: @isherwood jquery is available, I'm using it in the project in `main.js` script successfully.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack

Comment: @Sysix jquery works fine in the very same module.